# PHP Can't find class (composer autoloader, slim framework)

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

I'm developing an application via Slim framework and I made my classes to be loaded with composer.

When I'm running it locally via xampp, it totally works, but as soon as I upload it on a web storage, the following error occurs.:

```
Type: Error
Message: Class 'App\Controllers\UserController' not found
File: /some/path/backend/src/controllers.php
Line: 8
```

I uploaded my vendor directory also. Checked `get_declared_classes()` result, and my classes are actually not loaded. Could you make a hint, that where should I search for the solution?

Kind regards,
Daniel.

Comment: Do you include composer autoloader too?

Comment: I do it, otherwise it wouldn't work on localhost.  

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: It's also possible, that you have lowercase and uppercase letters mismatching (on Windows there is no difference between `UserController` and `usercontroller` while on Linux it's two different classes)

Comment: Well, I'm using camel-case for my classes, and in my composer.json I used the PSR-4 standard.

Comment: No, you were right. My directory names started with lowercase, and windows didn't give a .... about it, but linux does. Thank you!! Saved my day!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are programming locally using Windows and on server there is Linux, check that namespace and directory has same CamelCase naming, because Linux is case sensitive while Windows is case insensitive.